# ps -ef | grep * command not working properly

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have simple unix shell script as follows. Which is giving different count for a service

```
#!/bin/bash
service=$1

ps -ef | grep $service | grep -v "grep" | wc -l 
PROCESS_NUM=$(ps -ef | grep $service | grep -v "grep"| wc -l) 
echo $PROCESS_NUM
```

In the above code below line gives output of 2.

```
ps -ef | grep $service | grep -v "grep" | wc -l
```

But when same line is assigned to variable as code below its giving output as 3.

```
PROCESS_NUM=$(ps -ef | grep $service | grep -v "grep"| wc -l) 
echo $PROCESS_NUM
```

Why this is getting increased by 1 and how to tackle it.

Comment: When you do `X=$(...)` you are starting a subshell to execute the command so now you have the thing actually running and your shell script with it's command line param and the subshell that also mentions the process.  What you need is `ps -ef | grep $service | grep -v "grep" | grep -v "$0" | wc -l` which will get rid of the shell script and it's subshells.

Comment: Its worked. Thank you Jerry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what is happening if the script tees the output to a file before counting the lines and then displaying the output after:

```
#!/bin/bash
service=$1

echo Directly in Script:
ps -ef | grep $service | grep -v grep | tee test.txt | wc -l
cat test.txt

echo Inside Subshell:
RESULT=$(ps -ef | grep $service | grep -v grep | tee test.txt | wc -l)
echo $RESULT
cat test.txt
```

When the output of a command is captured, bash starts another shell to run the command - but that subshell also shows up in the process list.

When I run that script I get:

```
$ ./test.sh lca
Directly in Script:
2
gcti      4268     1  0  2018 ?        21:59:03 ./lca 4999
t816826   9159  7009  0 09:22 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh lca
Inside Subshell:
3
gcti      4268     1  0  2018 ?        21:59:03 ./lca 4999
t816826   9159  7009  0 09:22 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh lca
t816826   9166  9159  0 09:22 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh lca
```